# Вопрос по UTM-метках, не передаются в форме обратной связи, как решить?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Суть вопроса в самом вопросе: необходимо в форму обратной связи (Ajax) добавить захват UTM-меток и соответственно сделать их передачу на mail. Я добавил, но почему-то на почту они не приходят. Вот мой код:

HTML-код

```html
<form class="form-1" id="form-1">
  <div class="border__frame">
    <div class="heading">Отправьте <span>заявку на марс!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="description">И наш марсианский менеджер перезвонит вам в ближйшее время.</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_source']) ? $_GET['utm_source'] : '' ;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_medium" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_medium']) ? $_GET['utm_medium'] : '' ;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_campaign']) ? $_GET['utm_campaign'] : '' ;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_term" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_term']) ? $_GET['utm_term'] : '' ;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="utm_content" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_content']) ? $_GET['utm_content'] : '' ;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="с первого экрана Pop-up">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
    <input class="index__phone" name="code" type="tel" maxlength="3" placeholder="123" required>
    <input class="number__phone" name="tel" type="tel" placeholder="325-54-94" required>
    <button class="btn-submit-mars" type="submit">Отправить заявку на марс</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP-обработчик

```js
$recepient = "xxx@gmail.com";
$sitename = "Марсоход";

$formid = trim($_POST["formid"]);
$utm_source = trim($_POST["utm_source"]);
$utm_medium = trim($_POST["utm_medium"]);
$utm_campaign = trim($_POST["utm_campaign"]);
$utm_term = trim($_POST["utm_term"]);
$utm_content = trim($_POST["utm_content"]);
$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$code = trim($_POST["code"]);
$tel = trim($_POST["tel"]);
$message = trim($_POST["message"]);
$message = "форма $formid \nИсточник перехода: $utm_source $utm_medium $utm_campaign $utm_term $utm_content \nИмя: $name \nТелефон: $code $tel \nВопрос: $message";

$pagetitle = "Новое сообщение с сайта \"$sitename\"";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
```

js

```js
$("#form-1").validate({
  rules: {
    name: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },

    code: {
      required: true,
      digits: true,
      minlength: 3,
      maxlength: 3
    },

    tel: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 7,
      maxlength: 9

    }
  },
  messages: {
    name: {
      required: "Неверно заполнено поле :(",
      minlength: "Минимальное кол-во символов 2"
    },
    code: {
      required: "Введите код",
      digits: "Обязательно цифры",
      minlength: "3 символа"
    },
    tel: {
      required: "Введите номер телефона :(",
      minlength: "Необходимо 7 символов"
    }
  }
});

$("#form-1").submit(function() {

  if ($("#form-1").valid()) {
    var th = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mail.php",
      data: th.serialize()
    }).done(function() {

      $(".success").addClass("visible");
      setTimeout(function() {
        // Done Functions
        th.trigger("reset");
        $(".success").removeClass("visible");
      }, 1000);

      $('#form-1')[0].reset(
        setTimeout(function() {}, 1000)
      );

      $("#form-1").hide();

      $('.mfp-bg.mfp-ready').css({
        'display': 'none'
      });


      $('#popUpMessage').removeClass('hiddenDiv');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#popUpMessage').addClass('hiddenDiv');
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

в принципе ничего как будто сложного, но не работает. На форму приходит письмо: и там где Источник: .... Ключевое слово: ....
сама форма рабочая и проверена не раз.
Подскажите или покажите как правильно задать в форме эти метки, скажу честно google перерыл, примеры использовал - но толку никакого. Спасибо.

Comment: На просторах интернета наткнулся на информацию, что запрос в принципе создан правильно, но сами метки на сайте на настроены, соответственно захват не происходит, и как результат пустые поля.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Вы смогли передать UTM-метки, в форме обратной связи, у меня такой же вопрос? UTM-метки не передаются.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, в данном коде было несколько ошибок. В приведенном ниже примере они должны быть исправлены:

```
$("#form-1").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent doubly sending

  var form = $(this);

  if (form.valid()) {
    $.post({
      "mail.php",
      form.serializeArray().reduce(function(o, a) {
        o[a.name] = a.value;
        return o;
      }, {}), // post an object instead of string
      function(data) { // response from server is here
        form.submit(function(e) {
           e.preventDefault(); // no further submits allowed
        });

        $(":submit", form).prop("disabled", true);

        $(".success").addClass("visible");

        setTimeout(function() {
          form.trigger("reset").hide();
          $(".success").removeClass("visible");
        }, 1000);

        $('.mfp-bg.mfp-ready').css({
          'display': 'none'
        });

        $('#popUpMessage').removeClass('hiddenDiv');

        setTimeout(function() {
          $('#popUpMessage').addClass('hiddenDiv');
        }, 5000);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: спасибо, но эти как вы говорите ошибки совсем не влияют на решение моего вопроса, я вначале сказал: форма полностью рабочая, я просто добавил в нее захват utm-меток, которые теперь не отображаются в email.

Comment: @sagan, а если форму не через аякс отправлять, тогда что?

Comment: не понял к чему вопрос? что значит не через ajax? я делал как раз через ajax, и заказчик был за, кто будет менять по ходу?

Comment: работает форма, если напрямую сабмитить форму, а не ajax-ом? есть необходимые данные на почте?

Comment: еще один способ дебажить, это посмотреть вывод `print_r($_POST)`
туда точно все передается?